# Excel userform variable - can't find where declared or initialized

Tags: excel, vba, activex, 32bit-64bit

I'm working with a vendor's proprietary Excel add-in and ActiveX control (an ocx file). In trying to get it to work in 64-bit Office, I discovered that there's a variable, let's call it ABC, that TypeName says is, let's say ABC_DEF. That's the Excel name of the ActiveX control. Weird thing is, I can't find anywhere where the variable is declared or initialized - according to VBA's find, ABC_DEF isn't listed in the project anywhere (nor is the ActiveX control's filename), the form's object does not appear to have a visual object with the name ABC, and I've examined every reference to ABC in the code. Yet it's used throughout the code as the central object/variable, so clearly it's initialized somewhere - until run in 64-bit Excel, when it suddenly isn't.

I've tried

```
Dim ABC As new ABC_DEF
Set ABC = New ABC_DEF
```

which runs, but then doesn't behave as expected (underlying ActiveX control returns an error value when called).

Where could this be declared or initialized?

Comment: If its a control then it is probably inserted into a form in the form designer. Note `.ocx` files are `.dll` files. Programs can only use dll files of the same bitness. So 64 bit office requires a 64 bit ocx.

Comment: Have you tried using the Watch Window to debug when the value is set?

Answer (score 1):

It was a control on the userform, with the height set to 0. In the VBA window, in the Properties window, the dropdown allowed me to select it and set its height. Apparently, being a control, it's automatically initialized as part of the userform's initialization.

Thank you, user18521918.